# Introducing section headings in minted

Tags: sectioning, minted

I apologize if this has been answered elsewhere.  I haven't been able to find it.  I am using the `minted` package and I would like to have sections similar to

```
\section{Section Headings}
```

So I have two problems:

1. How do I use the latex command `\section` in the middle of the minted environment
2. I thought maybe I could just use `\end{minted}\section{My Section}\begin{minted}[ ... ]`, however this introduces a new problem where my line numbers start counting from 1 again in the new section, which I don't want.

Any help or insight would be much appreciated.

Comment: You can specify the number of the first line of the listing with `\begin[linenos,firstnumber=...,]`, although i'm affraid you need to manually insert the first line number yourself.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Without potentially painful tinkering with `minted` and/or `fancyvrb` internals, you will have to use the `firstnumber` option for the environment following the section, manually setting the starting line number, as @guillem said.

If you don't have to use `minted`, you could use my `pythontex` package (latest version on [GitHub](https://github.com/gpoore/pythontex), on CTAN soon).  It uses the same Pygments highlighting library that `minted` does and thus produces very similar output.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article} 

\usepackage[pygopt={texcomments=true}]{pythontex}
\setpygmentsfv[python]{numbers=left,firstnumber=last}


\begin{document}

\begin{pygments}{python}
def f(x):
    # Comment $x^2$
    return x**2
\end{pygments}

\section{A section}

\begin{pygments}{python}
def g(x):
    return x/2
\end{pygments}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Wow, pythontex seems quite cool.  I just finished watching your talk on Youtube.  Can I embed latex in my comments in pythontex like I can in mint.  I like that I can do something like "/* x = \frac{y}{z] */" in my C++-code and have it nicely rendered in my tex version of my code.

Comment: @HenryB. You can use Pygments' `texcomments` and `mathescape` features when loading the package.  You can also set these for individual languages, if you don't want the settings to apply to everything. I've updated the example to show `texcomments` in use.